# How do I increase my Word IQ?

Tags: quarrel

For some of the Domination games in *Quarrel*, you have to use a certain word IQ against a specific person.

How do I increase word IQ? Is it word length? Score? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's all about high-scoring words.

I know that in order to get a perfect 200 Word IQ, you'll have to make the best possible (aka the highest-scoring) word in every quarrel.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked around a bit as I was wondering the same thing and found the following, should it help anyone else:

1. As Krazer says, a Word IQ of 200 requires you to get the best scoring word each time.
2. Bonus words (the ones you make up in multiplayer whilst waiting for two others to battle) do NOT count.
3. I've found nothing to suggest that time comes into the calculation.
4. Length of word doesn't count for anything else in the game so would be surprised if it did here.

Taking a guess from here you would like to think that the calculation was something along the lines of:

[your word]/[best possible word] * 200

But who knows. ;)

Reference: http://www.denki.co.uk/games/quarrel/quarrel-faq/